# How to share a list object with custom form

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms

Am trying to share posted objects on list view but each time that I click on the share button which redirect me to share_form.html after typing into the shared textarea and submit the form it doesn't submit the shared object form, unless I use context variable {{ form }} before the object could be shared, why is it that when I use my custom form it doesn't submit the shared post? but rather when i do say {{ form }} then it's able to share the post?

```
Here is my view to share post

def share_post(request, pk):
    original_post = Post.objects.prefetch_related('postimage_set').get(pk=pk)
    form = ShareForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_post1 = Post(
            shared_body = request.POST.get('description'),
            description = original_post.description,
            username = original_post.username,
            date_posted = original_post.date_posted,
            video    = original_post.video,
            shared_on = datetime.now(),
            shared_user = request.user)
        new_post1.save()
        for image in original_post.postimage_set.all():
            new_post = PostImage(post=new_post1, 
                                username=original_post.username,
                                 image=image.image)
                
            new_post.save() 
        return redirect('feed:feed')
        
    ctx = {'form':form,'original_post':original_post}
    return render(request,'feed/share_form.html', ctx)
```

My django form model to share post!

```
class ShareForm(forms.Form):
    body = forms.CharField(label='',widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
    'rows': '3',
    'placeholder': 'Say Something...'
  }))
```

My html form to share post

```
<div class="main_content">
    <div class="mcontainer">
 
 <div class="md:flex md:space-x-6 lg:mx-16">
    <div class="space-y-5 flex-shrink-0 md:w-7/12">

 <div class="card lg:mx-0 uk-animation-slide-bottom-small">
   
  <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="flex space-x-4 mb-5 relative">
        <img src="{{ request.user.profile_image.url }}" alt="" class="rounded-full shadow w-12 h-12">
        <div class="flex-1">
            <form action="" method="POST" for='id_shared_body' enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                {% csrf_token %}
<div class="grid md:grid-cols-2 gap-4">
  <div class="col-span-2">
 <textarea name="shared_body" id="id_shared_body" cols="30" rows="6"  class="bg-gradient-to-b from-gray-100 to-gray-100"></textarea></div>
<a href="#" type="submit" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-md dark:hover:bg-gray-800">
<div class="uil-share-alt mr-1" type="submit"></div><button>Share Post</button></a>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- post header-->
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center lg:p-4 p-2.5">
        <div class="flex flex-1 items-center space-x-4">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="{{original_post.username.profile_image.url }}" class="bg-gray-200 border border-white rounded-full w-10 h-10">
            </a>
            <div class="flex-1 font-semibold capitalize">
                <a href="#" class="text-black dark:text-gray-100"> {{original_post.username.get_full_name}} </a>
                <div class="text-gray-700 flex items-center space-x-2">  <span> {{ original_post.date_posted|timesince }}  </span> <ion-icon name="people"></ion-icon></div>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div>
        <a href="#"> <i class="icon-feather-more-horizontal text-2xl hover:bg-gray-200 rounded-full p-2 transition -mr-1 dark:hover:bg-gray-700"></i> </a>
        <div class="bg-white w-56 shadow-md mx-auto p-2 mt-12 rounded-md text-gray-500 hidden text-base border border-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100 dark:border-gray-700" 
        uk-drop="mode: click;pos: bottom-right;animation: uk-animation-slide-bottom-small">
            <ul class="space-y-1">
              <li> 
                  <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-md dark:hover:bg-gray-800">
                   <i class="uil-edit-alt mr-1"></i>  Edit Post 
                  </a> 
              </li>
              <li> 
                  <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-md dark:hover:bg-gray-800">
                   <i class="uil-comment-slash mr-1"></i>   Disable comments
                  </a> 
              </li> 
              <li> 
                  <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-800 rounded-md dark:hover:bg-gray-800">
                   <i class="uil-favorite mr-1"></i>  Add favorites 
                  </a> 
              </li>
              <li>
                <hr class="-mx-2 my-2 dark:border-gray-800">
              </li>
              <li> 
                  <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 text-red-500 hover:bg-red-100 hover:text-red-500 rounded-md dark:hover:bg-red-600">
                   <i class="uil-trash-alt mr-1"></i>  Delete
                  </a> 
              </li>
            </ul>
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-3 border-b dark:border-gray-700">
        {{ original_post.description }}
       </div>
       {% if original_post.video %}
       <div class="w-full h-full">
              <video width="650" height="200" controls>
                <source src="{% static original_post.video.url %}" >
            </video>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-2 p-2">
      {% for p in original_post.postimage_set.all %}
      {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
     <a href="{{ p.image.url }}" class="col-span-2">  
     <img src=" {{ p.image.url }}  " alt="" class="rounded-md w-full lg:h-71 object-cover" >
     </a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}
    <a href="{{ p.image.url }}">  
     <img src="{{ p.image.url }} "  alt="" class="rounded-md w-full h-full">
    </a>
   {% endif %}

   {% if forloop.counter == 6 %}
    <a href="{{ p.image.url }}" class="relative"> 
    <img src=" {% if forloop.counter == 6 %}{{ p.image.url }}{% endif %}" alt="" class="rounded-md w-full h-full">
   <div class="absolute bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-30 flex justify-center items-center text-white rounded-md inset-0 text-2xl"> + {{ forloop.counter }} more </div>
   </a>
   {% else %}
   <a href="{{ p.image.url }}" class="relative" hidden> 
    <img src=" {% if forloop.counter == 3 %}{{ p.image.url }}{% endif %}" alt="" class="rounded-md w-full h-full">
    <div class="absolute bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-30 flex justify-center items-center text-white rounded-md inset-0 text-2xl"> + {{ forloop.counter }} more </div>
   </a>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
    <div class="p-4 space-y-3"> 
       
        <div class="flex space-x-4 lg:font-bold">
            <a href="#" class="flex items-center space-x-2">
                <div class="p-2 rounded-full  text-black lg:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-600">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" width="22" height="22" class="dark:text-gray-100">
                        <path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div> Like</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="flex items-center space-x-2 flex-1 justify-end">
                <div class="p-2 rounded-full  text-black lg:bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-600">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" width="22" height="22" class="dark:text-gray-100">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18 5v8a2 2 0 01-2 2h-5l-5 4v-4H4a2 2 0 01-2-2V5a2 2 0 012-2h12a2 2 0 012 2zM7 8H5v2h2V8zm2 0h2v2H9V8zm6 0h-2v2h2V8z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div>  Comment</div>
            </a>
            
        </div>
       
        {% for comment in original_post.g_comments.all %}
        <div class="border-t py-4 space-y-4 dark:border-gray-600">
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="w-10 h-10 rounded-full relative flex-shrink-0">
         <img src="" alt="" class="absolute h-full rounded-full w-full">
                </div>
                <div>
 <div class="text-gray-700 py-2 px-3 rounded-md bg-gray-100 relative lg:ml-5 ml-2 lg:mr-12 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-100">
 <p class="leading-6">{{comment}} <i class="uil-grin-tongue-wink-alt"></i> </p>
<div class="absolute w-3 h-3 top-3 -left-1 bg-gray-100 transform rotate-45 dark:bg-gray-800"></div>
                    </div>
<div class="text-xs flex items-center space-x-3 mt-2 ml-5">
 <a href="#" class="text-red-600"> <i class="uil-heart"></i> Love </a>
  <a href="#"> Replay </a>
                        <span> 3d </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <a href="#" class="hover:text-blue-600 hover:underline">  Veiw 8 more Comments </a>

        <div class="bg-gray-100 rounded-full relative dark:bg-gray-800 border-t">
            <input placeholder="Add your Comment.." class="bg-transparent max-h-10 shadow-none px-5">
            <div class="-m-0.5 absolute bottom-0 flex items-center right-3 text-xl">
                <a href="#">
                    <ion-icon name="happy-outline" class="hover:bg-gray-200 p-1.5 rounded-full"></ion-icon>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <ion-icon name="image-outline" class="hover:bg-gray-200 p-1.5 rounded-full"></ion-icon>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <ion-icon name="link-outline" class="hover:bg-gray-200 p-1.5 rounded-full"></ion-icon>
                </a> 
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>

</div> 
</div>
 </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after i had taken sometime to carefully analyzed the issue i had stable on a solution, actually the problem was coming from the form model:

```
 this where the problem was

class ShareForm(forms.Form):
    body = forms.CharField(label='',widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
    'rows': '3',
    'placeholder': 'Say Something...'
  }))
```

Instead i should have than something like this, i had omitted the description field, which was where my problem was !

```
class ShareForm(forms.Form):
    description = forms.CharField(
          label='',
  widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={
    'rows': '3',
    'placeholder': 'Say Something...'
  }))
```